# Explain the implementation of Scala's immutable List map method

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming, monads

I'm just trying to understand the logic behind the implementation of Scala's `List[A] map[B]`

Scala 2.12 describes it as such:

```
final override def map[B](f: A => B): List[B] = {
    if (this eq Nil) Nil else {
      val h = new ::[B](f(head), Nil)
      var t: ::[B] = h
      var rest = tail
      while (rest ne Nil) {
        val nx = new ::(f(rest.head), Nil)
        t.next = nx
        t = nx
        rest = rest.tail
      }
      releaseFence()
      h
    }
  }
```

I am confused as to how can `h` be a new list with `f` applied to each of its elements. `h` is declared as a val, so how can it be affected by what happens inside the `while` loop?

does reassigning the value of `t` retroactively changes the value of `h`? Wouldn't that make `h` mutable though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use as a reference [the version of `List.scala` on latest available commit on the `2.12.x` branch of the Scala repository on GitHub](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8a918b177a2b9ec4aacc03e5c54f9d0b042de5d6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala), which is slightly different but similar enough.

```
final override def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That = {
  if (isLikeListReusableCBF(bf)) {
    if (this eq Nil) Nil.asInstanceOf[That] else {
      val h = new ::[B](f(head), Nil)
      var t: ::[B] = h
      var rest = tail
      while (rest ne Nil) {
        val nx = new ::(f(rest.head), Nil)
        t.tl = nx
        t = nx
        rest = rest.tail
      }
      h.asInstanceOf[That]
    }
  }
  else super.map(f)
}
```

First notice that a `val` is an immutable *reference*, not a immutable *value*. You can mutate an object through an immutable reference if you have access to its mutable state. Notice how `t` is taken as a mutable reference to `h` (the value which is ultimately returned) and then a singleton list is associated with `t.tl = nx` (which corresponds to `t.next = nx` in your snippet, I believe).

That `tl` field is the tail of the `::` type, kept as mutable state for internal usage only, as you can see [here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/8a918b177a2b9ec4aacc03e5c54f9d0b042de5d6/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L479-L490):

```
/** A non empty list characterized by a head and a tail.
 *  @param head the first element of the list
 *  @param tl   the list containing the remaining elements of this list after the first one.
 *  @tparam B   the type of the list elements.
 *  @author  Martin Odersky
 *  @since   2.8
 */
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this mean that under the hood, an Immutable list is actually mutable? It sounds as if the `h` returned at the end of the method is actually a mutated version of the original object, instead of a new object based on the original.

Comment: The `h` instantiated in the `map` method is mutated internally and then returned, yes. The object itself is mutable, which means that if you cast the result of the `map` to the `::` inner class (assuming it's available externally) _and_ have your code live in the `scala` package, you can theoretically mutate the `List` by accessing `tl`. But it's probably easier to just use reflection and just mutate anything regardless. :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't make the original list mutable, only the copy you created within `map`. Also note that the Collection API has been completely revamped in 2.13, so this might now apply anymore.